# c++ Why does this work: cout << obj + (class_name)a << endl;

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

I am new to programming and I have started following a c++ course. But I am stuck in the lecture which is going about convert constructors and overloading operators. So I want to ask a question about the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Integer
{
public:
    Integer(){};
    Integer(int);

    int getNr();
    operator int();

private:
    int nr;
};

int main()
{
    Integer obj(5);
    int a = 20;

    cout << obj + a << endl; // prints 25

    return 0;
}

Integer::Integer(int nr)
{
    this->nr = nr;
}

int Integer::getNr()
{
    return this->nr;
}

Integer::operator int()
{
    return this->nr;
}
```

So from what I have understood so far is when the line: `cout << obj + a << endl;` is executed, something like `cout << obj + (Integer)a << endl;` happens, then both operands return 'nr' value.

Could anyone please explain to me what is happening in the background?

Will the convert constructor take 'a' as an argument and create an object with it?

Afterwards `operator int();` will be executed in both objects in order to return 'nr'?

Sorry if my question sounds silly, I am new to programming and I want to understand the logic behind it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When it sees, `cout << obj + a << endl;`, first checks if there is an `operator+()` that accepts an `Integer` and an `int`.   There isn't.   So the compiler looks at conversions.  `Integer` has an `operator int()`, so that is used first, and the result is the same as `cout << obj.operator int() + a`.  `obj.operator int()` returns an `int` with value `5`, which is added to `a` (which has value `20`).   So an integral value of `25` is output to `cout`.

Comment: Add debug logs like `std::cout << "I am calling constructor\n"` to every method you wrote and you will see what is called. This is the simplest. Running code under debugger is another option if you want to inspect the behavior like pros do.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - In the code given by the OP. `obj` is a variable, not a type.   So `(obj)a` is not valid code.

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk - In this case, tracking calls of constructors won't give useful information to the OP, since `cout << obj + a` does not call any constructor.

Comment: Just FYI, it is fun to study this, but in real life such a class (implicitly constructible from a basic type *and* implicitly convertible to a basic type) may get you into a lot of trouble. Don't do that.

Comment: @Peter thank you so much for your explanation! I can continue with my course now!